# Console.log doesn't work in React Native application after migration to TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

After adding dependencies and started project (still full of js code) in an ios simulator, `console.log` doesn't print anything.

I can check for sure that code gets called, but when I put `console.log` in any `js` file, or `ts` file with any argument nothing appears in my `TERMINAL`.

I use a VS Code if it matters somehow.
Also, I use expo

Not sure what info I can provide to diagnose, so if I can help to understand the issue somehow - please write.

Logs appear after I restart build. So I can see logs from previous run

Logs also appear in Chrome console, so the only place I can't see them is VS Code

Comment: You run in debugger mode and don't see any console inside chrome ?

Comment: @EQuimper, not really. I run it with `react-native-scripts start` and then `i` for iOS simulator

Comment: Ok but if you CMD+D choose `Run in debugger` this open a console in Chrome and you should be able to see that here.

Comment: @EQuimper, do you mean `Debug Remote JS`?

Comment: Yes @Vladyslav Zavalykhatko

Comment: @EQuimper, I'm able to see logs in Chrome. but not in VS Code. any ideas why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172342/discussion-between-equimper-and-vladyslav-zavalykhatko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get logs back using `exp start` instead

Answer (score 2):

For debugging and see the console.log the best way I found is by using `Debug Remote JS` after you have clicked on `CMD+D`. This way that open chrome and now you can see all your javascript log. Also a tool I use is https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger who let use the redux-devtool also. But for running it in expo you need to add this script in your package.json.

`"debug": "open 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=19001'"` This will open this debugger in the same port as expo.